# WSO2 Gadget cannot access SOAP payload

Tags: wso2, soapui, wso2-stratos

I have created a data service, which tests out correctly via TryIt and SoapUI. However, when I try to include it into a Gadget, I always get this error:

> "An error occurred while relaying a SOAP payload, to end point 
>   https://data.stratoslive.wso2.com/services/t/inova8.com/ProductVendorDataService.SOAP11Endpoint/"
>   The gadget includes this fragment: function doSOAPCall(){ var endpoint
>   = "https://data.stratoslive.wso2.com/services/t/inova8.com/ProductVendorDataService.SOAP11Endpoint/"; var payload = ""; var operation = "urn:getproduct";
>   document.getElementById("response-disp").innerHTML =
>   wso2.io.makeSOAPRequest(endpoint, operation, payload); }

The data service is based on the example http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/2011/11/expose-your-cloud-data-as-rdf-data-model.  Note that the operation needs no parameters, but I have tried every variant of a payload without success.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your steps and found that there are two issues with your gadget code segment to do a SOAP call.

First one is,since the operation you are accessing from data service end point,do not need any payload to pass to it.Such that inside the gadget xml you have to set payload as 'null'[NOT payload=""].

Second issue is that,your defined operation name in the gadget xml is incorrect.Once I tried your data-service by try-it option,I found that your accessing operation name is "_getProduct" and it's not "getProduct".

Once corrected above two issues,SOAP gadget works well with your end point and able to get response in to gadget from your accessing operation.The corrected code segment for doSOAPCall() function is as below.

function doSOAPCall(){ var endpoint = "https://data.stratoslive.wso2.com/services/t/inova8.com/ProductVendorDataService.SOAP11Endpoint/"; 
var payload = null;
var operation = "urn:_getproduct";
document.getElementById("response-disp").innerHTML = wso2.io.makeSOAPRequest(endpoint, operation, payload); }

Thanks;

Lalaji